# Registration of new bots for skype

Tags: botframework

I need to create a Skype bot, but registration of new bots was terminated.

In this regard, I have several questions:

Will an alternative technology for automatically sending messages to classic skype (No skype for business) be provided?

will registration of new bots be renewed, if so how soon?

is it possible to register a bot as an exception? Since it is extremely important for the further development of our software product.

Comment: Please see "[Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)"

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation

> As of October 31, 2019 the Skype channel no longer accepts new Bot publishing requests. This means that you can continue to develop bots using the Skype channel, but your bot will be limited to 100 users. You will not be able to publish your bot to a larger audience. Current Skype bots will continue to run uninterrupted. Learn more

You are still able to develop Skype bot but they will be limited to 100 users.

I think they are more focusing on **Microsoft Teams** instead.

Comment: The fact is that in my country 99% of the business of correspondence occurs through classic Skype. Change is extremely difficult. 100 contacts is enough for almost all needs.

Comment: Well according to the azure notice quoted above it seems that you are able to develop on Skype, have you tried and it did not work? If so, you can contact Azure support for that

Comment: I can only contact the support service by purchasing a license, but if this does not work out, it makes no sense to buy it.

Comment: Try submitting an issue here https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk you might get an answer directly from the bot framework team